# Field Specifier GeneXus

Tags: genexus

Al intentar crear un grid con un listado de valores definidos en un dominio. Utilizo una grid con una de coleccion a la que le asigno el domain.Elements().

El problema que tengo es que en las propiedades de la variable hay una propiedad llamada 'field property' la cual su valor por defecto es 'item(0)' y no encontre documentacion de a que hace referencia esa propiedad. Dejo captura del error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El item(0) refiere a lo que seria el "current item", te dejo informacion sobre dicha propiedad en el wiki:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?47238,Field%20Specifier%20properties